# Disable rails route based on flag/constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've got a rails engine that has a simple constant defined in it.

```
require 'my_engine/engine'
module MyEngine
  OPEN_SIGNUPS = false
end
```

in my routes I have something like

```
if MyEngine::OPEN_SIGNUPS
  get 'sign_up'
else
  get 'request_access'
end
```

Basically if I haven't enabled the sign up feature, the user can request access to the beta.

Unfortunately this is proving really difficult to test bc I think the routes file is only loaded once (using rspec here). I tried stubbing out the constant with

```
stub_const("MyEngine::OPEN_SIGNUPS", true)
```

to test the open version, but I'm having issues getting it to work.

Is there a better way to have "conditional" routes based on a simple flag or constant. Some combination of `constraints`, perhaps? At this point I'm thinking of just adding ALL the routes and checking in each controller if OPEN_SIGNUPs isn't on, and redirect to the request access page if it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, routes are only loaded once when your rails server is started, so what you have is only evaled on start.  But you can add dynamic stuff using lambdas or any other function.

```
get 'signups', to: 'something#index', constraints: lambda{ |request| MyEngine::OPEN_SIGNUPS }

get 'request_access', to: 'other_thing#index', constraints: lambda{ |request| !MyEngine::OPEN_SIGNUPS }
```

Here is a link to advanced constaints. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Personally, i have only used constraints to restrict access to certain areas based on permissions.  You may be better off to just have two routes and do a redirect in the controller based on the value in your module.

Comment: This works well, thanks Austio. I think I've decided to refactor to make OPEN_SIGNUPS an env variable instead, so we'll see where that goes.